# How to change device volume from seek bar in android

Tags: android

I know how to control volume of media player from seekbar.But how can i do to change system volume from seekbar in android.

Comment: This is a more easy http://stackoverflow.com/a/13733061/1939564

Answer (score 6):

Use `AudioManager` and methods like [`adjustStreamVolume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29). [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Volume) that uses `SeekBar` widgets to adjust the volumes of various streams.

Answer (score 5):

The following code can be used :

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.SeekBar;

import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;

private AudioManager audioManager = null; 

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initControls();
}

private void initControls()

{

    try
    {
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the volume scale linear? I read somewhere that it should be logarithmic.