# How to show Android system volume control programmatically

Tags: android, audio, volume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to control volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117051/how-to-control-volume-in-android)

How to show Android system volume control programmatically? As if the physical volume+/- button is pressed.

On Android 4.x

Comment: somewhat different - I wanted to know how to show the system volume control

Comment: as your comment below does solve the problem, kindly add it as an answer and accept it

Comment: very misleading duplicate, not a duplicate at all

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `setStreamVolume()` method. There are a lot of options available, check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#FLAG_SHOW_UI

Comment: Thanks, this does it:                AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME,
                                         AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);

Comment: Do not use *AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME* - if you use it, and then user will change volume, and then you'll use it again - **it set the same volume as the first time**. Use: 

audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)